# RegEx in ExpressJS Route

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

In ExpressJS, how to right the following in one route using RegEx?

```
app.get('/blog', blog.list);
app.get('/blog/p/:page?', blog.list);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What the point of using RegExp here? Express patterns is simpler, yet almost as powerful as regular expressions:

```
app.get('/blog(?:/p/:page([0-9]+)?)?', blog.list);
```

This route will match all of the following urls:

- `/blog`
- `/blog/`
- `/blog/p`
- `/blog/p/`
- `/blog/p/123`

In `blog.list` controller `req.params.page` will contain page number or will be `undefined` if it wasn't supplied.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be compelling reasons to make these separate routes, but I'm not sure what you are doing with your app.

```
app.get(/^\/blog(?:\/p\/([0-9]+)?)?/, blog.list);
```

req.params[0] should be "20" at the route /blog/p/20, with req.params as `null` for /blog/p/ or /blog/ but with with both as functional routes.